# Python connection to AWS Athena throwing error

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am trying to run AWS Athena SQL queries via Python 2.7.13 and followed the below two options but getting **"python.exe stopped working"** error in both cases.
I am new to python any help is much appreciated.

Option 1: Tried using Pyathenajdbc

```
>>> from pyathenajdbc import connect

>>> import pandas as pd

>>> conn = connect(access_key='<acess_key>',
               secret_key='<secret_key>',
               s3_staging_dir='s3://Test/',
               region_name='<region_name>',
               jvm_path='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre6\\bin\\client\\jvm.dll')

>>> df = pd.read_sql("select * from test.test45 LIMIT 1", conn)
```

Option 2: Tried using  jaydebeapi  still the same error

[image: Screenshot of Error msg]

***Error Message in Python debug using Microsoft Visual studio***

Unhandled exception at 0x00170000 in python.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.

Comment: Here is the similar thread, perhaps it has something to do with your imports http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40178251/pyqt5-script-got-error-bex-in-module-stackhash

Comment: or maybe you have a problem with the pandas version? Pandas pip install PyAthenaJDBC[Pandas] >=0.19.0 (ref https://github.com/laughingman7743/PyAthenaJDBC )

Comment: I tried with your code which doesnt use Pandas and still got the same error. On your comment on cleaning up the imports i installed "Pyflakes" and trying to figure out how to implement in the code to do the cleanup.

Comment: Also just noticed in the error screenshot  that Application version is 0.0.0.0 instead of 2.7.13 not sure if  this is causing any err. However Python -V in cmd prompt returns version as 2.7.13.Any thoughts?

Comment: Used Pyflakes to check on imports and it didnt highlight any issue.

Comment: Pardon me, I honestly don't know what is causing the issue. Check this link perhaps it may help you https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3932e3eb-c034-4eb7-aa06-4a0a8e6ea493/fault-module-namestackhash0a9e?forum=w7itprogeneral  Best of luck ^^"

Comment: ah yes and consider changing the tags of the thread. I believe it is related to python, windows, microsoft, BEX, DEP ... more than pyathenajdbc or aws :)

Comment: If you're new to Python you shouldn't be using Python 2 unless you *absolutely* have to.

Comment: What about uninstalling and reinstalling python? Also try running the code on another machine? I am just interested in seeing if this has something to do with your particular machine and install.

Comment: You might want to take the time to configure a virtual machine image to give a clean environment to work from.

Comment: @WayneWerner my AWS code is written in python 2.7 so i have to go by that

Comment: @Code-Apprentice tried reinstallling Python & ran my code in my colleagues machine still getting the same error. I didn't try the VM image option so far.

Answer (score 2):

JayDeBeApi is way too complicated to adjust with Athena JDBC, PyAthenajdbc is easier to use.
This is how I am using it and it is working like a charm!

## Declaration

```
import os
import configparser
import pyathenajdbc


# Get aws credentials 
aws_config_file = '~/.aws/config'

Config = configparser.ConfigParser()
Config.read(os.path.expanduser(aws_config_file))

access_key_id = Config['default']['aws_access_key_id']
secret_key_id = Config['default']['aws_secret_access_key']

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
log_path = BASE_DIR + "/lib/static/queries.log"

class PyAthenaLoader():    
    def connecti(self):
        self.conn = pyathenajdbc.connect(
            s3_staging_dir="s3://athena",
            access_key=access_key_id,
            secret_key=secret_key_id,
            region_name="us-east-1",
            log_path=log_path,

        )

    def databases(self):
        dbs = self.query("show databases;")
        return dbs

    def tables(self, database):
        tables = self.query("show tables in {0};".format(database))
        return tables


    def query(self, req):
        self.connecti()

        try:
            with self.conn.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(req)
                res = cursor.fetchall()
        except Exception as X:
            return X
        finally:
            self.conn.close()
        return res
```

## Usage

```
athena = PyAthenaLoader()
res = athena.query('SELECT * from shadow.sales;')
print(res)
```

Comment: - Many Thanks for your input however I am getting "python.exe has stopped working" error even in this code. Not sure if I am missing any parameters or system variables before running the script?

Comment: I see. I am using Gnu/Linux OS so I have never encountered that error. However, I have done some researches and apparently this issue may be related to various causes. Could you post a screenshot of the error perhaps others may help you?

Comment: As requested added error screenshot to the question

Comment: jpype._jexception.RuntimeExceptionPyRaisable: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaDriver not found

Comment: The creator of PyAthenaJDBC recommands using his other module based on the newly released boto SDK : https://github.com/laughingman7743/PyAthena